# How can I Delete Data in a Database Using ComboBox in C#?

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio, combobox

[Here is a Picture of My Table Named `CategoryTable`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/StZlN.png)

I used The Following Code to Delete Data from the Above Table using a `ComboBox` which is named as `SelectCategoryComboBox`But it does nothing.it acts like an un-programed button.
here is my code:

```
try
{
  String conString =   ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["mfcdb"].ConnectionString;
                     String query = "DELETE FROM CategoryTable WHERE     CategoryName='" + SelectCategoryComboBox.SelectedText + "'";

    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conString))
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
        con.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
  }
  catch{
  MessageBox.Show("Error");
}
```

Comment: That is the wrong way to compose SQL - use SQL parameters.  `SelectedText` is probably not what you think it is - consult the documentation.  And you are hiding the real error from yourself by simply reporting "Error".  There is plenty of *good* db related code here and on MSDN.  Also, blockquotes are not for code

Comment: but the catch block didn't run as well..as I said it acts like an un-programed button...sorry for the mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
SelectCategoryComboBox.SelectedText
```

to

```
SelectCategoryComboBox.SelectedItem.ToString()
```